# Dependency Injected APIs in custom Actions

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, guice

I am currently migrating a Play 2.3 project into Play 2.4 and am facing some problems doing so. 
Starting with Play 2.4, some API's as WSClient and DBApi are being injected into the controllers by Guice.

```
class MyController @Inject() (ws: WSClient, db: DBApi) extends Controller {}
```

Now the problem I am facing is that I need those API's within some custom actions and I am wondering how I am supposed to provide the actions with those API's.

One obvious way of doing it would be explicitly passing those arguments to the action like this:

```
object MyAction(p: Privilege.Value, db: DBApi, ws: WSClient) extends ActionBuilder[Request]{}
```

And then call the action like this:

```
class MyController @Inject (db: DBApi, ws: WSClient) extends Controller {
  def blubb = MyAction(Privilege.admin, db, ws).async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    Future.successful(Ok("just a demo"))
  }
}
```

But I would rather like to submit those injected API's implicitly somehow like this:

```
object MyAction(p: Privilege.Value)(implicit db: DBApi, ws: WSClient) extends ActionBuilder[RequestContext] {}
```

And the calling it like this, like I did it ever since ;-)

```
class MyController @Inject (implicit db: DBApi, ws: WSClient) extends Controller {
  def doSomething = MyAction(Privilege.admin).async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    Future.successful(Ok("just a demo"))
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work...

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Best regards
Samuel

Comment: Did you try to just inject it into the action?^^

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?
case class MyAction @Inject (ws: WSClient) extends ActionBuilder[Request]{} doesn't work, if its that what you mean ;-)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, I'm struggling with the same problem and can't seem to find a good solution.

Comment: @henrik
Yes, I posted it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally discovered a solution thanks to Johan Andrén: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/aUIjB2R6BE4

He basically suggests to create a trait like this:

```
trait Authentication {
  def db: DBApi
  def ws: WSClient

  case class DataAction(privilege: Privilege.Value) extends ActionBuilder[RequestContext] with I18nSupport {
    // use db and ws to do your thing
  }
}
```

which will then be mixed in the required controller.

```
class MyController @Inject (val db: DBApi, val ws: WSClient) extends Controller with Authentication {
  def doSomething = Authenticated(Privilege.admin).async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    Future.successful(Ok("just a demo"))
  }
}
```